# how would i sort directorys to the top of the list without having to change the list (its sorting alphabetically right now) in lua

Tags: list, sorting, lua

```
if command == "dir" then
        local filelist = fs.list("")
        for _, file in pairs(filelist) do
            if fs.isDir(file) == true then
                term.setTextColor(8)
                print(file)
                term.setTextColor(colors.yellow)
            else
                term.setTextColor(1)
                print(file.." "..fs.getSize(file))
            end
        end
    end
```

this is the code i have it goes through each item and then prints the item and if its a file it prints how big the file is and it changes the text color depending on if its a directory or not but i also want the directory's to be at the top but i dont know how to do that so i need some help

Comment: i did it i got it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
if command == "dir" then
        local filelist = fs.list("")
        for _, file in pairs(filelist) do
            if fs.isDir(file) == true then
                term.setTextColor(8)
                print("- "..file)
                term.setTextColor(colors.yellow)
            end
        end
        for _, file in pairs(filelist) do
            if fs.isDir(file) == false then
                term.setTextColor(2)
                print("- "..file.." "..fs.getSize(file).." bytes")
                term.setTextColor(colors.yellow)
            end
        end
    end
```

i did it